Getting Big Crushed by Big Crush
So I've been trying to learn some new skills by crafting a novel encryption method. It's going well so far, 8.000 entropy, perfect nist and dieharder(one weak lag sum). However when I run it through Big Crush I get this. What i'm doing is encrypting 1.5gb of data and trying to make it appear totally random. So I can piggyback on the random data and make it look just like it.
Consistent Failures in Chi-square and SimpPoker Tests:
Extremely low p-values (≈ 0) indicate significant deviations from expected distributions, suggesting non-randomness in the RNG.

Inconsistent Performance in Collision Over Tests:
While some tests pass (p-value > 0.05), others fail, indicating variability in the RNG's collision resistance depending on parameter configurations.

Recurring Failures in Birthday Spacings and Close Pairs Tests:
Multiple instances of low p-values across different settings point towards inherent issues in maintaining expected randomness patterns.

Its driving me nuts. Is there like a rookie mistake I am making running the tests? Maybe prepping the data wrong, or like a file size issue or something? How big does my test data need to be is 1.5-2 gb too small? Or does my encryption just suck?

"It's going well so far, 8.000 entropy, perfect nist and dieharder (one weak lag sum)" Beware that passing these tests could be considered a pre-requisite for a cipher. But passing these tests does not prove that the algorithm is a CSPRNG and it certainly doesn't show that a cipher is secure. Attackers are considered to know the algorithm and may attack the inner structure instead.

These algorithms are very data hungry; I'd simply try with the largest test set feasible. 15 GiB is nothing these days. See if that makes a difference - if it does: great, if it doesn't it won't have hurt much.

@Maarten Bodewes - Thanks I'll give it a try. I think its pretty secure but I haven't optimized it to be attack resistant yet mostly focusing on encrypting the text but you can set the bit key length to whatever you want really. Some of my runs I made a 1gb bit key length just for the laughs. I think it would be super hard to break without having the key, although knowing me I probably did something wrong somewhere, but it will be easily fixable.
